# Getting error while using constants in functions as a parameter

Tags: php

**Here php code**

```
define('SITE_NAME','example');
define('SITE_EMAIL_ID','abc@exampl.com');

function sendmail($to, $subject="Mail from ".SITE_NAME, $message=null, $from=SITE_EMAIL_ID, $bcc=null, $cc=null)
    {
    .....
    }
```

**shows error** 
*Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ')' in functions.php on line 4*

Answer (score 0):

```
define('SITE_NAME','example');
define('SITE_EMAIL_ID','abc@exampl.com');

$subject="Mail from ".SITE_NAME;
function sendmail($to, $subject , $message=null, $from=SITE_EMAIL_ID, $bcc=null, $cc=null)
    {
    //
    }
```

Comment: Could you explain your code?

Answer (score 0):

Change from

```
function sendmail($to, $subject="Mail from ".SITE_NAME, $message=null, $from=SITE_EMAIL_ID, $bcc=null, $cc=null)
```

To

```
function sendmail($to, $subject="Mail from {SITE_NAME}", $message=null, $from=SITE_EMAIL_ID, $bcc=null, $cc=null)
```

> Or

You can assign value of constant to variable before `function` like

```
$subject="Mail from ".SITE_NAME;
```

Then change from

```
function sendmail($to, $subject="Mail from ".SITE_NAME, $message=null, $from=SITE_EMAIL_ID, $bcc=null, $cc=null)
```

To

```
function sendmail($to, $subject , $message=null, $from=SITE_EMAIL_ID, $bcc=null, $cc=null)
```

Comment: Thanks dear hassaan but {SITE_NAME} is printed as it is. It is not working then before function assign itbto variable is not suitable for my criteria. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please read this link

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

### However, this feature is included as of PHP 5.6.0. See this page for more information: http://php.net/migration56.new-features#migration56.new-features.const-scalar-exprs

"The default value must be a constant expression" is misleading (or even wrong).  PHP 5.4.4 fails to parse this function definition:

```
function htmlspecialchars_latin1($s, $flags = ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401) {}
```

This yields a

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting ')'

although `ENT_COMPAT|ENT_HTML401` is certainly what a compiler-affine person would call a `constant expression`.

The obvious workaround is to use a single special value ($flags = NULL) as the default, and to set it to the desired value in the function's body

```
if ($flags === NULL) { $flags = ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401; })
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot do that. PHP does not allow variable names as default values for a function.